# DPDK: Malformed packets Bogus IP length and Bad UDP length in DNS query packet

Tags: c, dpdk

I am using dpdk-stable-19.11.10 version for my project. Basically I am building a DNS standard query message and sending to a DNS server/responder across a router(DUT). I am facing issue when I receive packets at DNS server that, some packets are malformed due below reasons:
Bogus IP length, bad UDP length and DNS malformed packets.

First case:I am building a DNS query packet as below:

````
m = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(info->q[qid].tx_mp);

dns_qhdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(m, struct dns_question_t *);
(.....dns question header)
pkt_size += sizeof(struct dns_question_t);

query_name = (unsigned char *)rte_pktmbuf_prepend(m, (strlen(dns_application_data) + 1));
prev_str_len = (strlen(dns_application_data) + 1);
memset(query_name, 0, prev_str_len);
strncpy((query_name), dns_application_data, (strlen(dns_application_data)));
pkt_size += (strlen(dns_application_data) + 1);

dns_hdr = (struct dns_new_hdr_t *)rte_pktmbuf_prepend(m, (uint16_t)sizeof(struct dns_new_hdr_t));
(.....dns header)
pkt_size +=  sizeof(struct dns_new_hdr_t);

udp_hdr = (struct udphdr *)rte_pktmbuf_prepend(m, (uint16_t)sizeof(struct udphdr));
l4_len = L4_UDP_HDR_SIZE + pkt_size;
udp_hdr->len = htons(l4_len);

ip_hdr = (struct iphdr *)rte_pktmbuf_prepend(m, (uint16_t)sizeof(struct iphdr));
ip_hdr->tot_len = htons(pkt_size + L3_IPV4_HDR_SIZE);

eth_hdr = (struct ethernet_hdr *)rte_pktmbuf_prepend(m, (uint16_t)sizeof(struct ethernet_hdr));

m->data_len = m->pkt_len = pkt_size;
rte_memcpy((struct rte_mbuf *)(store_packets[streams]), m, mbuf_len);
send_mbuf(m, port, qid);(calling ```rte_eth_tx_burst``` to send packets).
````

I offloading checksum to HW with ol_flags and I don't issues with it.

I have don't have any issues if I send packets like above. But If I try to send packets in below format I am seeing issue on rx port(at DNS server).

Second case:
So instead of building each packet header values I am using `rte_memcpy` to copy packet and storing into an array,
`rte_memcpy((struct rte_mbuf *)(store_packets[streams]), m, mbuf_len);`

later using `rte_pktmbuf_clone` to clone the packet
`m = rte_pktmbuf_clone((struct rte_mbuf *)(store_packets[streams]), info->q[qid].tx_mp);` and `rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset` to change DNS,UDP,IPV4 and ETHERNET headers values.

```
pkt_size = 0;
dns_hdr = (struct dns_new_hdr_t *) rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset(m, struct dns_new_hdr_t *,sizeof(struct ethernet_hdr) + L3_IPV4_HDR_SIZE  + sizeof(struct udphdr));

unsigned char *query_name = (unsigned char*) rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset(m, struct dns_qhdr *,sizeof(struct ethernet_hdr) + L3_IPV4_HDR_SIZE + sizeof(struct udphdr) + sizeof(struct dns_new_hdr_t));
prev_str_len = (strlen(dns_application_data) + 1);
memset(query_name, 0, prev_str_len);
strncpy((query_name), dns_application_data, (strlen(dns_application_data)));


dns_qhdr = (struct dns_question_t *) rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset(m, struct dns_question_t*,(sizeof(struct ethernet_hdr) +  L3_IPV4_HDR_SIZE + sizeof(struct udphdr) + sizeof(struct dns_new_hdr_t) + prev_str_len));

pkt_size += sizeof(struct ethernet_hdr) +  L3_IPV4_HDR_SIZE + L4_UDP_HDR_SIZE +  sizeof(struct dns_new_hdr_t) + sizeof(struct dns_question_t) + prev_str_len;

ip_hdr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset(m, struct iphdr *, (sizeof(struct ethernet_hdr)));
ip_hdr->tot_len = htons(pkt_size - sizeof(struct ethernet_hdr));

udp_hdr = (struct udphdr *)  rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset(m, struct udphdr *,sizeof(struct ethernet_hdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr));
l4_len = sizeof(struct dns_question_t) + sizeof(struct dns_new_hdr_t) + prev_str_len + L4_UDP_HDR_SIZE;
udp_hdr->len = htons(l4_len);

m->data_len = m->pkt_len = pkt_size;
rte_eth_tx_burst();
```

Since IPV4 and UDP length is depended on DNS query message I am updating IP4 total length and UDP length at last.

I am recalculating the packet size after cloning the packet(depending upon the DNS query message pkt_size may vary) and sending.
`m->data_len = m->pkt_len = pkt_size;`

I used `rte_pktmbuf_mtod_offset` to alter the all (L7 to L2)header values after cloning the packets still I am seeing ***Bogus IPV4 length, Bad UDP length and Malformed DNS packets***.

Please find the drive link for tx and rx pcaps.
`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UsJFAOG2AjtT1-5n2kgVKpm6xKkWV96W?usp=sharing`
The packets sending before cloning and after cloning should be same.
Can anyone point me what is messing up here?!
Thanks

Comment: the fields in the structs are likely not nul-terminated strings.

Comment: no its nul-terminated strings. 
```dns_application_data[strcspn(dns_application_data, "\n")] = 0;
              prev_str_len = (strlen(dns_application_data) + 1);```

Comment: Then why do you need to cast in the assignments?

Comment: you mean the query_name?

Answer (score 0):

If there are any pointers(for DNS Names) in `dns_question_t` and `dns_new_hdr_t` structures, Check `pkt_size` value. You need to calculate IPV4 & UDP header length properly including the pointer value size.
Please share the sample packet which you are sending with the error which helps to debug.

Comment: I have shared the drive link which consists of tx and rx pcaps